# can I use an integer in case statement in verilog?

Tags: verilog

I am not sure whether the following is valid code in Verilog. More specifically, can one use an integer in a case statement as a condition, as in:

```
input [2:0]W;
integer k=1;
output [7:0]Y;
case (W)
k:y[k]=1;
endcase
```

Comment: why you need the integer?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: if you're looking to use a label for your case instead of a raw value, perhaps consider using a `parameter` or `localparam`?

Comment: At least with this code, why not just `y[W] = 1;`?

Answer (score 0):

In the posted question your output Y is upper-case, the y in the assign is lower-case, once this is resolved case statements can not stand on their own, they need to be inside an always or an initial block.

For example:

```
always @* begin
  case (W)
    k: y[k]=1;
  endcase
end
```

An integer is just a 32 (or 64) bit reg. Syntactically no different using an integer instead of reg.